# Issue when running application in devspaces under AKS cluster

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, azure-dev-spaces

I created an AKS cluster with http enabled.Also I have my project with dev spaces enabled to use the cluster.While runing azds up the app is creating all necessary deployment files (helm.yaml,charts.yaml,values.yaml).However I want to access my app using a public endpoint with dev space url but when I do azds list-uris it is only giving localhost url and not the url with dev space enabled.

Can anyone please help?

My azds.yaml looks like below

```
kind: helm-release
apiVersion: 1.1
build:
  context: .
  dockerfile: Dockerfile
install:
  chart: charts/webfrontend
  values:
  - values.dev.yaml?
  - secrets.dev.yaml?
  set:
    # Optionally, specify an array of imagePullSecrets. These secrets must be manually created in the namespace.
    # This will override the imagePullSecrets array in values.yaml file.
    # If the dockerfile specifies any private registry, the imagePullSecret for that registry must be added here.
    # ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#specifying-imagepullsecrets-on-a-pod
    #
    # For example, the following uses credentials from secret "myRegistryKeySecretName".
    #
    # imagePullSecrets:
    #   - name: myRegistryKeySecretName
    replicaCount: 1
    image:
      repository: webfrontend
      tag: $(tag)
      pullPolicy: Never
    ingress:
      annotations:
        kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik-azds
      hosts:
      # This expands to form the service's public URL: [space.s.][rootSpace.]webfrontend.<random suffix>.<region>.azds.io
      # Customize the public URL by changing the 'webfrontend' text between the $(rootSpacePrefix) and $(hostSuffix) tokens
      # For more information see https://aka.ms/devspaces/routing
      - $(spacePrefix)$(rootSpacePrefix)webfrontend$(hostSuffix)
configurations:
  develop:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.develop
      useGitIgnore: true
      args:
        BUILD_CONFIGURATION: ${BUILD_CONFIGURATION:-Debug}
    container:
      sync:
      - "**/Pages/**"
      - "**/Views/**"
      - "**/wwwroot/**"
      - "!**/*.{sln,csproj}"
      command: [dotnet, run, --no-restore, --no-build, --no-launch-profile, -c, "${BUILD_CONFIGURATION:-Debug}"]
      iterate:
        processesToKill: [dotnet, vsdbg, webfrontend]
        buildCommands:
        - [dotnet, build, --no-restore, -c, "${BUILD_CONFIGURATION:-Debug}"]
```

I followed below guide
https://microsoft.github.io/AzureTipsAndTricks/blog/tip228.html

AZDS up is giving end point to my localhost

Service 'webfrontend' port 80 (http) is available via port forwarding at http://localhost:50597

Comment: did you foliw any guide or docs?

Comment: Yes I followed https://microsoft.github.io/AzureTipsAndTricks/blog/tip228.html

Answer (score 1):

Has your azds.yaml file ingress definition to the public 'webfrontend' domain?
Here is an example azds.yaml file created using .NET Core sample application:

```
kind: helm-release
apiVersion: 1.1
build:
  context: .
  dockerfile: Dockerfile
install:
  chart: charts/webfrontend
  values:
  - values.dev.yaml?
  - secrets.dev.yaml?
  set:
    replicaCount: 1
    image:
      repository: webfrontend
      tag: $(tag)
      pullPolicy: Never
    ingress:
      annotations:
        kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik-azds
      hosts:
        # This expands to [space.s.][rootSpace.]webfrontend.<random suffix>.<region>.azds.io
        # Customize the public URL by changing the 'webfrontend' text between the $(rootSpacePrefix) and $(hostSuffix) tokens
        # For more information see https://aka.ms/devspaces/routing
        - $(spacePrefix)$(rootSpacePrefix)webfrontend$(hostSuffix)
configurations:
  develop:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.develop
      useGitIgnore: true
      args:
        BUILD_CONFIGURATION: ${BUILD_CONFIGURATION:-Debug}
    container:
      sync:
      - "**/Pages/**"
      - "**/Views/**"
      - "**/wwwroot/**"
      - "!**/*.{sln,csproj}"
      command: [dotnet, run, --no-restore, --no-build, --no-launch-profile, -c, "${BUILD_CONFIGURATION:-Debug}"]
      iterate:
        processesToKill: [dotnet, vsdbg]
        buildCommands:
        - [dotnet, build, --no-restore, -c, "${BUILD_CONFIGURATION:-Debug}"]
```

More about it: https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/azure/dev-spaces/how-dev-spaces-works-prep

How many service logs do you see in 'azds up' log, are you watching something similar to:

```
Service 'webfrontend' port 'http' is available at `http://webfrontend.XXX
```

Did you follow this guide?
https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/azure/dev-spaces/troubleshooting#dns-name-resolution-fails-for-a-public-url-associated-with-a-dev-spaces-service

Do you have the latest version of the azds?

Comment: My azds.yaml file looks exactly the same.azds version is 1.1.azds up is giving "Service 'webfrontend' port 80 (http) is available via port forwarding at http://localhost:50597"

Comment: @GauravBhardwaj Does `azds up -v` with verbose gives some more info?

Comment: No it does not however I got the issue,Somehow when I am building the solution in Visual studio I am not getting the public  url path howevr If I run same solution in VS code,I am getting that url and things are working as expected,seems some weird issue in Visual Studio 2019 tool.

Comment: @GauravBhardwaj Maybe let them know